# Getting key value but not the root value of Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node which I am trying to get the key of the value. The node looks like this:

```
roomMembers
- "user1_user2"   (roomname)
  - user1: true
  - user2: true
- "user1_user3"  
  - user1: true
  - user2: true
```

I am trying to retrieve and know "user1_user2" and "user1_user3" by both using `.Value` and `.ChildAdded`.

```
let membersRef = Firebase(url: self.dataURL + "/roomMembers")

membersRef.queryOrderedByChild("user1").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

     snapshot.value   // returns the objects as `[String: [String:Bool]]`
     snapshot.key     // returns 'roomMembers'
})
```

When I use `.ChildAdded`, it only returns one value

```
membersRef.queryOrderedByChild("user1").observeEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

     snapshot.key     // returns the right level, but only returns "user1_user2".
     snapshot.value  // also returns only one value
```

How can I get "user1_user2" and "user1_user3" (all roomnames)  with a single query using `.Value` and `.ChildAdded`?

---

Edit:

Assume I have a node like this:

```
 lastMessages
  - "user1_user2"
    - -KJrqHaMzA9Hi-RS_ieV     (timestamp'ed id)
        - sender
        - message
        - opponent_seen

  - "user1_user3"
    - -KJrqHaMzA9Hi-RS_ieB
        - sender
        - message
        - opponent_seen
```

How can I get timestamped keys and their values?

Comment: what is the problem with using `.Value` code you added ?

Comment: In `.Value`, `snapshot.value` is returning the whole object as `["user1_user2": ["user1": true, "user2"], "user1_user3": ["user1": true, "user2"]]`, and I couldn't figure out how to get only the room names. Also, I think I shouldn't use `observeEventType` for `.Value` because it won't stop observing. However, I think I should handle `.ChildAdded` and `.ChildChanged` separately. Is that wrong?

Comment: use `snapshot.value.allKeys() ` to get all room names

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works like charm for `.Value`. Just one more question; what is the way of achieving the same level with `observeEventType(.ChildAdded)`?

Comment: @senty same answer ... but child added calls on every child added ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all room names ...You have to get **allKeys** like

```
  snapshot.value.allKeys()
```

This will give you `["user1_user2","user1_user3"]` i.e your roomnames.

Comment: I have another question regarding the same topic. I added an edit on the bottom of my question. Can you please explain this too? Is there a way of using up and down of the node levels? Thanks

Comment: Yes that's right. For this example, I used `snap.value.allValues` and it gives me [timestamps: ["key":"value"]. If I use, `snap.value.allKeys` it gives me roomnames level.

Comment: firebase gets things like URL ... like `yourfirebasereference/roomMembers/user1_user2` ... like wise ... so if you want timestamp of `user1_user2` ... you have to make query through timestamp root